# Created or modified within... full path file listing from tree

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need a list of files, within a directory and its subdirectories, which were created or modified within the last seven days. The listing must be in the format of their fully qualified absolute paths.

I am trying the code below, but it's not working.

```bash
@Powershell -NoP -C "&{$ts=New-TimeSpan -Da 7;" "GCI $(GCI \"H:\Molding\Molding Parameters\"|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|?{$_.LastWriteTime -gt ((Get-Date)-$ts)}|%%{$_.FullName}) -R|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|Select FullName,LastwriteTime|Export-csv -NoT \"C:\MoldPara\Bhavesh.csv\""
Pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Get-ChildItem 'FILE PATH HERE' -Recurse -file | Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
```

You can swap the "LastWriteTime" for other date properties like CreationTime, or LastAccessTime, to suit your requirements.

You can also stack multiple together in the where like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'FILE PATH HERE' -Recurse -file | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) -or ($_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7))}
```